# bubble unhandled exception to white automation from silverlight

Tags: silverlight, exception, automation, ui-automation, white-framework

I am using the white automation API to test a silverlight app, but when an unhandled exception occurs in silverlight I don't know of a way to report this back to the unit test or check in the white api to see if there was an exception.  Anyone got a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the white test framework, but you can probably do something like the following in your test:

```
[Test]
public void MyTest()
{
    bool unhandledExceptionFired = false;
    Application.Current.UnhandledException += (s,e) => unhandledExceptionFired = true;

    //test code....


    Assert.IsFalse(unhandledExceptionFired);
}
```

Like I said, I have not used the particular test framework mentioned, but something like this should work. Or are you running into some problem that prevents this from working?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this won't work as I am not working directly with the silverlight app - it is being automated - basically this simulates user interaction on the app ie button clicks, enter text etc so it is external to the app - this is a functional test framework, along the lines of selenium for web apps.  I can see the IE 'error on page' warning so I know the exception is fired in the app but it doesn't get reported in the white api (or I can't find a way to get to it anyway).

Answer (score 0):

The IE 'error on page' warning is a GUI element, so you should be able to check for it via the white api. Locate the IE status bar, query it for the status message, and if the message == 'error on page', then log an error in your test. Sample code below for inspecting the text on the status bar.

```
app = Application.Attach(Process.GetProcessesByName('iexplore')[0])
win = app.GetWindows()[0]
statusBar = win.Get(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId('StatusBar'))
for item in statusBar.Items:
    print item.Id, String.Format("'{0}'", item.Text)
```

output

```
StatusBar.Pane0 'Done'
StatusBar.Pane1 '' 
StatusBar.Pane2 ''
StatusBar.Pane3 '' 
StatusBar.Pane4 ''
StatusBar.Pane5 '' 
StatusBar.Pane6 ''
StatusBar.Pane7 'Internet'
```